# How can I check and verify whether predefined date is reached or have passed in php?

Tags: php

[image: My Code Result]I Want to check if current date is the same as my predefined date and if it is the same then the script should display a message showing how many days left for the predefined date to be reached or whether the date is reached, or passed.
I am developing an app which I want to check if the current date is for example 25th, and if it is then a Generate Payslip Button should display else if the date is not reached the remaining days left for the specified date to be reached should be display else the number of days after the specified date (e.g. 25th ) should be displayed.
Here is my code:

```
$payday = 20;//int e.g 25
$now = date('d');
if ($now < $payday) {

    echo 'Pay Day Less';
} else if ($now == $payday) {
    echo '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="salary-view.php?staff_id=<?php echo $result["id"] ?>">Generate Slip</a>';
} elseif ($now > $payday) {
    echo 'Pay Day Passed';
} else {
    echo 'You are faking us';
}
```

Comment: $now is a string, not a DateTime object, so you can't call the "format" method on it.

Comment: i dont see any `format` method used, $now is a string but its converted to int so the if's are ok, what is wrong is the `<?php` inside text, just replace `<?php echo $result["id"] ?>` to `'.$result["id"].'`

Comment: @Kazz that's because it's been edited since I commented. Check the question history. But you're right, you can't echo inside an echo, that makes no sense. I hadn't spotted that.

Comment: @ADyson but the echo is working only that the output is different from the code logic the script runs and the echo inside does not work so rewrite the code they you feel it will work best

Comment: Even if it doesn't crash, probably the link it generates is not valid due to the extra echo - check the final page source in your browser

Comment: @ ADyson, Yes you are right, then put up the code you feel will work perfectly. I am looking for a perfect solution. My worry is that no one has try to write a single line of code on this question. I want to know if today is 25th of the month and echo result accordingly

Comment: You sometimes find that people comment first, to try and help you in the right direction to solve it yourself. I'm on a mobile right now so can't test any code before posting it. If I get chance later I will try to post a full answer. In the meantime...what result is it producing now instead of what you expected? You didn't mention. And what have you done so far to try and debug it?

Comment: @ADyson, The result I am getting is that when I assure 30 to variable paydate, the script shows the Generate button whereas it should display Pay Day Passed which logically is on the last elseif statatem. That is after rearranging the statement logic. if fact the script is displaying result in reversed manner which I have tried switching he logic but could not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$payday = 20; //int e.g 25
$now = intval(date('d')); //convert to int for convenient operations
if ($now < $payday) {
  $daysToPayday = $payday - $now;
  echo 'Pay Day Less';
} else if ($now == $payday) {
  echo '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="salary-view.php?staff_id=<?php echo $result["id"] ?>">Generate Slip</a>';
} elseif ($now > $payday) {
  $daysAfterPayday = $now - $payday;
  echo 'Pay Day Passed';
} else {
  echo 'You are faking us';
}
```

If your problem is just days before/after then this should be all. Display $daysToPayday, $daysAfterPayday as you please.